# Bind Form from javascript Play framework

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to use this code:

```
Form<StatusSolicitacao> status = form(StatusSolicitacao.class).bindFromRequest();
```

But the data coming from a javascript?

--- More information ---

First i show the list:

```
<div id="backtabela">
    <div id="tabela">
        <table>
        <tr><td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('formCadStatus')" id="botao">Cadastrar Status</a></td></tr>  
            <tr>
                <td id="cabecalho">Descrição</td>
                <td id="cabecalho">Acoes</td>
            </tr>
            @for(status <- lista){
            <tr>
                <td>@status.getDescricao()</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('formAltStatus/@status.getCodStatus()')"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("img/edit.png")" alt="" title="Editar"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('removerStatus/@status.getCodStatus()')"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("img/erase.png")" alt="" title="Remover"/></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then i click on the Cadastrar Status to register a new data.

The form:

```
@(status: Form[StatusSolicitacao])

@import helper._
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(formPattern.f) }


        <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
        <fieldset id="fieldset">
        <legend>Novo Status</legend>
        <div id="form">         
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        @form(routes.StatusController.cadastrarStatus()) {
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    @inputText(status("descricao"), '_label -> "Descrição", '_help->"")            
                <div class="actions">
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn primary" id="botao">                  
                </div>
          </div>
          </fieldset>
           <a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('listarStatus')" class="btn">Cancelar</a> 
            }
```

Note: All this content is inside the div nova in this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Solicitação Compra</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/geral.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("img/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/init.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="geral-flow">
    <div id="topo">
        <div id="logo" style="display:none;">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("img/logotipo-pequeno.png")" alt="titulo" id="tituloPequeno"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="acessos">
            <div id="pesquisa">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Pesquisa"
                    onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value='Pesquisa'"></input>
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="acessoRapido" >
                <a href="@routes.DepartamentoController.deslogar()" title="Sair" id="sair"></a>
                <a href="@routes.Application.index()" title="Home" id="home"></a> 
                <a href="#" title="Pesquisa" id="pesquisar"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="conteudo">
    <div id="titulo">
                <ul>
                <li style="background-position:-2px -107px;"><h2>Solicitações</h2></li>
                </ul>
            </div>              
    <div id="separador"></div>  
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="solicitacao"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('listarSolicitacaoCompra')">Solicitaçoes</a><br /></li>  
                <li class="departamento"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('listarDepartamento')">Departamentos</a><br /></li>             
                <li class="responsavel"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('listarResponsavel')">Responsavel</a><br /></li>
                <li class="status"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('listarStatus')">Status</a><br /></li>            
            </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="nova"></div>

     <div class="clear"></div>     
    </div>
    </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

but when I save my new record on the bench in the back that html does not appear.

Comment: What's the difference? It is a Http form submitted right?

Comment: Its because I update the contents with a javascript, if I do the normal mode, after finishing it shows only the contents, without the rest of the page

Comment: I don't understand a thing...? What normal mode? What do you mean by data coming from javascript? Show us more code

Answer (score 0):

javaScript or not basically its a post request if your name attributes coincide the StatusSolicitacao attributes i believe it will work

else just use the following `String attribute = Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("attribute");`